# Styling only multiple paragraphs

Tags: css, css-selectors

I was wondering how this can be done.
Under each paragraph I want a 30px margin bottom, but only on articles with more then one paragraphs. How can I fix this?

I look out to your advice :)

Casper

Comment: Try using $('p').css('margin-bottom', 30);

Comment: @ahmad: that'd apply to ALL paragraphs

Comment: Ok, so let's try this `if ($('article').children().length() >= 2) { $(this).find('p').css('margin-bottom', 30); }`

Comment: You'll have to use it

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about `<p>` tags, using the following css selector:

```
p + p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Would add a top margin of `30px` to every paragraph that follows another paragraph... Would be the same effect as you asked.

http://jsfiddle.net/g91afp8z/

Comment: No it wouldn't - the last one wouldn't have a `margin-bottom`?

Comment: Although not mentioned in the question, it would be enough if the point is adding the margin between the paragraphs...

Answer (score 1):

Actually it depends on your markup, however you may be able to target the `<p>` elements which are not the only of their type in their parent - the article - as follows:

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/0n4dnp8c/6/)

```css
article > p:not(:only-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

If you want to exclude the last paragraph, add `:not(:last-of-type)` as well:

**[EXAMPLE HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/0n4dnp8c/5/)**

```css
article > p:not(:only-of-type):not(:last-of-type) {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}
```

It's worth noting that [`:not`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:not), [`:only-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:only-of-type) and [`:last-of-type`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:last-of-type) pseudo classes are not supported in IE 8 and below.

---

You could also fake the effect by adding `margin-top` to the **2nd, 3rd, 4th, ...** paragraphs instead, by using [General sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors) `p ~ p` which is supported in IE7+ as well.

[**EXAMPLE HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/hashem/0n4dnp8c/4/)

```css
article > p ~ p {
    margin-top: 30px;
}
```

Comment: Note that this is not supported in IE <9